# python api https://agsi.gie.eu/

Tags: python, api

I am trying to connect to https://agsi.gie.eu.
I do not know why I get no access

thx

```
import requests as rqs

url='https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000013279/UA'

user='my email'

password='my key'

response=rqs.get(url,auth=(user,password))

print(response.status_code)

print(response.content)
```

I get

```
200

b'{"error":"access denied"}'
```

Comment: Please edit your post with proper formatting

Comment: Read the API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with an API, you want to make sure to read the developer's instructions / API documentation. And i can clearly tell you haven't done that.

Go ahead and give the [GIE API Documentation](https://agsi.gie.eu/GIE_API_documentation_v004.pdf) a read. Will help you sort out future issues.
The part that refers to your issue is the following.

> **6.4 Importing data - cURL**
>   Using the links from the previous pages and your API key, you can send requests to the
>   API to get the data in JSON format;
>
> ```
> curl https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X-BE-A-A0A0A-Y/
> BE --header "x-key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> ```
>
> If the API key is not supplied or incorrect, the return value is an error message;
>   `{"error":"access denied"}'`

You can clearly see that the api uses `x-api-key` header for authentication, and not email/password

Comment: Thank You so much, I am begginer in Python so I was looking topic in web and I found some answears to VBA (which I know) and I was trying to modyfy it to Python. Your one comment saved me so much time (I regret I havn`t asked before I spent half day looking in Web). Thank you.